# Is triple 4k (120hz, 60hz, 60hz) possible with RTX 2070?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, 4k-resolution

I would like to know if I can run three 4k monitors as follows:

1. 120hz 4k via display port 1
2. 60 hz 4k via display port 2
3. 60 hz 4k via HDMI port

Below is my config

- CPU: intel core i5 9400f
- GPU: RTX2070 with 2 display ports and 1 HDMI
- Motherboard: Asrock taichi z390
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 using nvidia-driver-450

EDIT:
The actual graphics card is [INNO3D GEFORCE RTX 2070 TWIN X2](https://www.inno3d.com/products_detail.php?refid=397)

Also, would this CPU be enough (no gaming; just programming) or should I look at upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the actual card & manufacturer.

NVidia don't make graphics cards, they make graphics chipsets. (The founder's edition cards are usually built by PNY).
The chipset from NVidia can do 4 x 4k displays… but only if the card manufacture built that support into their card.

The solution is to check the actual model spec on the card manufacturer's site, not at NVidia.

Comment: Added details of my graphics card

Comment: Then that's where you find your info. I don't see refresh rate mentioned anywhere & it only mentions max resolution & 'multi-displays'. You might have to dig deeper. the way they list the output ports, though, makes me think some of those are shared.